# Data validation from getline in C++

Tags: c++, getline

I want to ask the user if they want to continue playing another round or quit. If they want to continue I expect them to enter two words in getline, but if they enter quit, I want to break;. Is this possible?

Can I check to see if the first letter is a "q" and then use putback if it is not? Or can I check the whole word and putback if it is not quit (I would not know the length of the word). Id there some other way I can approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you post some code. Are you actually using `getline`? And then checking the input one letter at a time?

Comment: You can't put back anything more than a single character. Can't see why reading a whole line, checking if it's "quit" and then carrying on processing if it is not, doesn't work. Agree that (as always) some code helps to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I recommend using getline to read each line of user input.  Then parse the string in order to determine what action to take.  I don't see how a putback would be useful if it were possible.     If necessary you can use a stringstream to get numeric info out of the string, or you can simply compare characters.  It is up to you to determine the approach but there are a variety of ways in which you could design the program.

Take a look at this.  Try to avoid the common gotchas associated with standard streams otherwise you will soon be googling for answers to other questions.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/input-output.html